# What does the "production" config parameter in parse-dashboard do?

Tags: parse-server

I'm just setting up parse-dashboard and all my parse-server apps have a "DEV" label beside them.  According to [this change](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/pull/219), I can change that to read "PROD" by setting the "production" config parameter to true.

My question is, apart from the change in the label, are there any behavioural or functionality changes in parse-dashboard or parse-server by setting an app to production: true?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parse-server you are right there is no difference it's just a visual thing to know that this app is your "production" so you should be aware to not treat it as DEV because in DEV you can do some testing and delete objects manually etc.

The **original** production flag was introduce in parse.com was to allow the parse.com team to scale your app performance according to the traffic (as shown in the image below)

[image]

Comment: Hi @ran-hassid.  Thank you for taking the time to provide your feedback.